# How to think about iterated ultrapowers?

Tags: logic, set-theory, large-cardinals

I would like to gain some basic intuition about iterated ultrapowers. I am perfectly happy with accepting the construction and can see that it fits into a fundamental role in many places (for example, it seems to be the correct way to compare tiny structures in inner model theory via various coiteration lemmas), but I'm having trouble seeing what happens morally when we take iterated ultrapowers.

For example, suppose $\kappa$ is the least measurable and $U$ a normal measure on it. In the ultrapower, $j(\kappa)>\kappa$ is now the least measurable. If we keep on iterating through $\mathrm{Ord}$ we will eventually push all measurables out of existence. So in this sense the final model is smaller than the one we started with (this is apart from the fact that the ultrapowers are constructed internally to $V$ and are thus trivially smaller in a very boring sense).

But on the other hand, if $(L_\alpha,U)$ is a mouse with the top cardinal $\kappa$, the ultrapower must, by elementarity, be $L_{j(\kappa)^+}$, and after iterating through $\mathrm{Ord}$ we get to $L$. So these ultrapowers seem to grow.

What I'd ultimately like to know is whether, heuristically speaking, iterating ultrapowers "adds stuff" or "takes stuff away". What kind of thought process should I go through when looking at a problem to be able to say, "Ah, I will iterate this ultrapower and then everything will be great"?

Comment: What I'd ultimately like to know is whether, heuristically speaking, iterating ultrapowers "adds stuff" or "takes stuff away".-------The intuition is that it does both.

Comment: Since you mention inner model theory, reading the proof of a comparison argument may help (for instance, in Steel's Handbook paper, but even Kunen's early result has the key ideas). The point is that when you compare two (fine structural) models, typically you look at the first point where they disagree, and typically the disagreement is that some set is in an ultrafilter in one model, but not in the corresponding ultrafilter in the other. Taking the ultrapowers effectively removes this disagreement (the culprit ultrafilters are no longer present). So the new models agree for a longer segment.

Comment: Fondly. Think of them fondly. :-)